# inflexion point how to find it?

Tags: real-analysis

Can someone explain me this part of wikipedia I don't understand it

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point#A_necessary_but_not_sufficient_condition

Comment: you must have $f''(x_0)=0$ to have an inflection point, but not all points with $f''(x_0)=0$ are inflection points

Comment: but they say: f''(x_0) exists and x_0 is an inflexion point then f''(x_0)=0, it is in the first line of the part, this do not give us the inflexion point what is it ? @J.W.Tanner

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of POSSIBLE inflection points,(i) where $f''(x_0)=0$ and (ii)where $f''(x_0)$ does not exist.First, find all the points where $f''(x_0)=0$. At each such point, investigate whether $f''(x)$ is positive on one side of $x_0$ and negative on the other for $x$ close enough to $x_0.$ Such points are inflection points. Second, find all the points where $f''(x_0)$ does not exist.At each such point investigate whether $f''(x)$ is positive on one side of $x_0$ and negative on the other for $x$ close enough to $x_0.$ Such points are inflection points.

Comment: I am a bit surprised that you are focusing on a "necessary condition for an inflection point" but not mentioning the **definition** of an inflection point.  An "inflection point" of a curve is a point at which the curvature changes sign.  Since the curvature is proportional to the second derivative, that would be equivalent to the second derivative changing sign.  And then, **if** you are requiring that the second derivative be continuous, the second derivative must be 0 at that point.  Of course, as P. Lawrence said, it is possible for the derivative to be 0 but not then change sign.